# Reactor WebFlux: help to understand how to work flatMap()

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

Please help to understand how can I use fkatMap() in my example:

```
Flux.just("1,2,3", "4,5,6")
                .flatMap(// to do something)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

I read the documentation. I understood how to work flatMap() but I can't understand how I need to use in my example.
Thanks.

Comment: `String.split(",")` looks like a good choice for a flatmap operation here. Can you guess why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kayaman already answered, you can do the following:

```
Flux.just("1,2,3", "4,5,6")
        .flatMap(i -> Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(i.split(","))))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Could you tell me where I can practice some examples? When I read the theory, then everything is clear to me, but when I need to write code, I have difficulties. I will be very grateful to you!

Comment: I'm very pleased to hear that :) I'd recommend to watch the videos where Oleg Dokuka is a speaker. He's mad about reactivity. He also has a book "Reactive Programming in Spring 5" there are a lot of examples there as well.

Comment: And I think you've already realised that this reactive stuff is a bit different from what we used to do with Java. So it's completely ok, that you can't immediately jump in. Practice more and the things will get more clear to you soon. Have a good coding!